# TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined - Data an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter

I am trying to map some array items into filter drop-downs to sort the array output. However, i'm getting an error - 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined '. I'm pretty sure this is down to data being an object. I'm quite new to JS so unsure what the next best step is.

Any pointers on whats going on & what I need to change would be great. Please let me know if you need any more info. -

```
import React, { useState, Fragment } from "react";
import { graphql } from 'gatsby'

const Page = ({data}) => {
  console.log('data is', data)
  const [filters, setFilters] = useState({
   type: "",
   propertyStatus: ""
 });

  const filteredProperties = data.edges.nodes.filter((node) =>
    Object.entries(filters).every(([filterName, filterValue]) => {
      if (filterValue === "") {
        return true;
      }

      return node[filterName] === filterValue;
    }),
  );

  return (
    <Fragment>
      {Object.entries(filters).map(([filterName, filterValue]) => {
        const allValuesForFilterKey = data.edges.nodes.map(
          (node) => node[filterName],
        );
        const uniqueValuesForFilterKey = [...new Set(allValuesForFilterKey)];

        return (
          <label style={{ marginRight: 10 }}>
            <span style={{ marginRight: 5 }}>{filterName}:</span>
            <select
              value={filterValue}
              onChange={(event) => {
                event.persist();
                setFilters((previousFilters) => {
                  return {
                    ...previousFilters,
                    [filterName]: event.target.value,
                  };
                })
              }                
             }
            >
              <option value="">No filter</option>
              {uniqueValuesForFilterKey.map((value) => (
                <option value={value}>{value}</option>
              ))}
            </select>
          </label>
        );
      })}

      <ul>
        {filteredProperties.map((node) => (
          <li>
            {node.name}
            <br />
            type: {node.type}
            <br />
            category: {node.category}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </Fragment>
  );
}

export const query = graphql`
  query yourQueryName{
      allStrapiHomes {
        nodes {
          type
          propertyStatus
        }
      }
  }
`

export default Page
```

The console log output is this

[image]

Comment: You have a typo there. Change this line ```data.edges.nodes.filter``` to this ```data.edges.filter```. Simply because ```data.edges``` is an array and ```filter``` is an array method :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data.edges` is the array and `data.edges.nodes` will be undefined.

[`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is the method of array.

```
const filteredProperties = data.edges.filter((edge) =>
    Object.entries(filters).every(([filterName, filterValue]) => {
      if (filterValue === "") {
        return true;
      }

      return edge.node[filterName] === filterValue;
    }),
  );
```

Comment: Thanks! Changed to data.edges & its now letting me see the UI, it has the correct amount of items however all the fields and drop-downs are blank. Guess this is due to not indicating index but i'm not really sure how to do so, any pointers?

Comment: Sorry still the same issue with the new code

Comment: did you also update in the render?
const allValuesForFilterKey = data.edges.map(
          (edge) => edge.node[filterName],
        );